# Concentrate two rows in mysql, but keep column names

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

Mysql (v. 5.1) db of domain and the number of Facebook shares.

tblFacebook

```
+------------+--------+----------+
| day        | shares | domainid |
+------------+--------+----------+
| 1571011200 |    441 |        1 |
| 1571097600 |    443 |        1 |
| 1571184000 |    474 |        1 |
| 1571270400 |    518 |        1 |
| 1571184000 |    849 |        3 |
| 1571270400 |    849 |        3 |
+------------+--------+----------+
```

I'd like to see the following output:

```
+------------+------------------+------------------+
| day        | domainid1-shares | domainid3-shares |
+------------+------------------+------------------+
| 1571011200 |    441          |                  |
| 1571097600 |    443          |                  |
| 1571184000 |    474          |  849             |
| 1571270400 |    518          |  849             |
+------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

How?

I did try this, but it did not give me the two separate columns (domainid1-shares and domainid3-shares)?

```
SELECT day, GROUP_CONCAT(shares SEPARATOR ', ') FROM tblFacebook GROUP BY day;
```

Comment: This is called a *pivot*. You can look up how to do it. It's a notorious pain in the neck in MySQL.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    day,
    max(case when domainid = 1 then shares end) domainid1_shares,
    max(case when domainid = 3 then shares end) domainid3_shares
from mytable t
group by day
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8e2b6f9f53a5fb8571df130b7389f28)**:

```
       day | domainid1_shares | domainid3_shares
---------: | ---------------: | ---------------:
1571011200 |              441 |             null
1571097600 |              443 |             null
1571184000 |              474 |              849
1571270400 |              518 |              849
```